# Tips for formatting your answers

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, markdown

Is there any place where I can find tips to make my answers and questions more presentable and readable ?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox

Comment: You mean like the [editing help](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) section?

Comment: Yes please. And tips to make my questions attract more readers so I have better chances of getting a good answer and quick

Comment: If your question is properly formatted, precise, with a SSCCE and clearly explains what the problem is, you'll surely get very good answers, pretty quickly. This would attract the readers more than any other fancy stuffs, IMO.

Comment: We don't have a style guide. I don't think I have ever seen one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To start off, there is the Markdown Editing Help button:

> [image: markdown editing help question mark button]

After clicking that, you can go to the [editing help section](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) via the advanced help link:

> [image: advanced help link]

That is, if the inline help isn't enough already:

> [image: inline help]

Clicking on a heading gives you details:

> [image]

---

Tips for getting answers:

- [How can I get answers fast?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8010/how-can-i-get-answers-fast)
- [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)
- [Short, Self Contained Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org/)