# Adding Code So People Can See The Code

Tags: support

I am unable to add code to my question I want to ask. How do I add code to a question so that people can see the code?

Comment: You simply paste it into the same textbox that you type your answer. Code should be indented by at least 4 spaces, if you highlight the code and then click the curly brackets button above the editor it will do this for you.

Comment: Also check this related question: [Tips for formatting your answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202312/146015)

Comment: Are you having a problem editing the question? There should be an `edit` link under your question that you can use.

Comment: I assume you're asking about [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21879285/revisions). Don't use backticks if there are multiple lines of code. Paste the code as plaintext, select it and press Ctrl + K (or `{}` button in the formatting toolbar)

Comment: Thanks slugster got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to use four spaces for code. So regular text just type as you would. But when you want to post code indent four spaces and then add the code.