# Where can I ask this question about programming language?

Tags: support, asking-questions

Question:

> How first programming language made?

Description:

> I want to know how first programming language made?

Comment: Welcome to Meta :) What has Web searches yielded so far?

Comment: @Arian If Web searches don't answer what you're looking for, then you will likely need to flesh out your question, such as being more specific about you're specifically looking for (e.g., what do you consider the minimum requirements for something to be a "programming language"), for it to be acceptable on basically any of the SE sites. Then the topic you're asking about may be applicable to the [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) site, but you should still check their help center to confirm this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/282094) and   https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8010/282094

Comment: In the body: That is ***not*** how [questions are formed in English](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4yWEt0OSpg&t=1m49s) (QUASM). It is missing the auxiliary (or helping) verb.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I'm going to be that guy and suggest you [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20was%20the%20first%20programming%20language%20made&oq=how%20was%20the%20first%20). You are going to find lots of great starting points there, and might find your answer already there.

For example [you would find it was asked on SO and closed as off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4772768/674571) years ago.

I would also suggest taking note of something on many of the [site help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page

The question without a lot of context might not do so well. Picking a specific proto language or context might help as would using SE to augment your own basic research